# Url get axios works in react and postman but gives 403 error in node Js

Tags: node.js, api, axios, backend, mern

I am trying to make an api call using axios in node js but it gives me 403 error I don't know why

```js
const http = require("http")
const axios = require("axios");
const app = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
})

const test = async() =>{
  const res = await axios.get("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode=110017&date=10-05-2021")
  console.log(res)
}

test()
app.listen(4000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 4000')
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Are you setting any headers in the requests from Postman or React? `Authorization` for example

Comment: no i did not set any header in postman or react and this endpoint does not require any authorization key @Phil

Comment: You might be getting rejected due to the user-agent in that case. Try [changing it](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2560)

Comment: @SamShaw: What was the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-agent and some proxy in between rejected my requests. Killed half a day trying to figure that out.